# Reverse effect of Join in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm developing a system and creating invoices. I want the record where no invoice has been created.

I'm trying to write a MySQL query, where I need the records whch can not be joined with another table. In other words, the records that do not have a linked record in the other table.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT exports.id as e_id,export_invoices.id as i_id 
FROM exports 
LEFT JOIN export_invoices ON export_invoices.export_id = exports.id
```

and got this result:

[image]

Which gives all value and also the record of which invoice is not created with NULL value (I want to have that [e_id->2 from result]). I just want to extract that null value record's master id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the where condition in your query -

```
SELECT exports.id as e_id,export_invoices.id as i_id 
FROM exports LEFT JOIN export_invoices on export_invoices.export_id = exports.id
WHERE export_invoices.id IS NULL;
```